# row_array() codeigniter return the first row only

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get list of email addresses from the database, what I have tried are here:

In my model:

```
function get_email_address_by_sector($search_by, $search_field) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->like($search_by, $search_field);
        $query = $this->db->get('tb_company');

        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row['email'];
    }
```

I want to see the data in the array with this controller:

```
function get_email_address($search_by, $search_field) {
        $recipients = $this->company_model->get_email_address_by_sector($search_by, $search_field);

        print_r($recipients);
    }
```

There are 2 records, and must be show both of them. But it shows the first record only.
Is there any wrong in my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`row_array()` returns the first row only. If you want all the records to be returned, use `result_array()` instead

```
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$row = $query->row_array(); // it will only one row.
```

use `result_array()`

`$row = $query->result_array();// it will return all rows`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = $query->first_row('array');
return $result;
```

Comment: I think you mean: `$query->getFirstRow(‘array’) ` https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html  Even if you think a solution is basic/simple/self-explanatory, you should still add some kind of explanation or supporting text.  Code-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Furthermore, an answer is only for the OP on this page -- it speaks to everyone who reads this page AND if it is used to close a new question, it will speak to that OP and those researchers as well.

Comment: The fact of the matter is, the OP doesn't want the first row.  The OP wants to grab multiple rows.  This makes your answer incorrect  ( or put more gently -- it is the correct answer to a different question).